# How to do a regex for $ symbol and 1-6 all capital letters for a stock symbol?

Tags: php, regex

It seems that it's common practice to "tag" stock symbols like this - $SYMB.  How would you build a regex to find & replace in PHP?

Here is a similar code I use for swapping out URLs -

```
$body = preg_replace('#(\A|[^=\]\'"a-zA-Z0-9])(http[s]?://(.+?)/[^()<>\s]+)#i', '\\1<a href="\\2">\\3</a>', $body);
```

With that concept, I would try to assume this -

```
$body = preg_replace('|$[A-Z]|i', '\\1', $body);
```

BUT it doesn't work.  Can somebody please explain their solution so that I can understand why it works?

Comment: What is your expected input and output?

Comment: Replace $SYMB with SYMB.  The idea is just to get the regex to find $SYMB in the format of '$' + 1-6 capital letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$body = preg_replace('/\$([A-Z]{1,6})/', '\\1', $body);
```

[Example](http://3v4l.org/ek3La)

---

## Explination

`(...)` Groups everything matched inside `...`

`{1,6}` will match the previous rule 1 to 6 times

`\1` or `$1` will match the first group, replacing with it will replace it with the first matched group.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  I'll add additional code trying this example on my question.

Comment: In non-literal strings (double quoted strings) `$var` will be filled in with the value of `$var`, you have to either use literal strings (single quoted strings) or escape the `$` by doing `\$`. [Example](http://3v4l.org/P9dP7)

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense.  So I just did a simple `str_replace('$','\$',$body)` before that regex line and it works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like [$A-Z] should work